Is this production/transportation problem solvable?
I am trying to solve the following problem.
Consider a scenario with $m$ factories producing a product and $n$ customers. Production at factory $i=1,\dots,m$ costs $c_i\geq 0$ per unit of product, as long as a quantity of at most $A_i$ is produced: the cost is incurred by $κ_i\geq 0$ per additional unit of product.  Each customer $j=1,\dots,n$ requests to receive product quantity $d_j\geq 0$.
Transporting product from factory $i$ to customer $j$ costs $t_{ij} \geq 0$ per unit, as long as a quantity of at most $B_{ij}$ is transported: the transportation cost is incurred by $r_{ij}$ per additional unit of product.
It is asked to decide how much product to produce at each factory $i$ and how much to transport from each factory $i$ to each customer $j$ so as to minimize the maximum total production cost and total transportation cost.
I have done the following to formulate this in a mathematical way.
Let $x_i$ be the amount that is produced by factory $i$ and $y_{ij}$ the amount that is transported from factory $i$ to customer $j$.
The production cost is $$PC_i=\begin{cases}
c_ix_i, & \text{ if } x_i\leq A_i\\
c_iA_i+k_i(x_i-A_i), & \text{ if } x_i> A_i\\
\end{cases}$$ We can simplify that as follows : $$PC_i=c_i\cdot \min(x_i, A_i)+k_i\cdot \max(0, x_i-A_i)$$
The transportation cost is $$TC_{ij}=\begin{cases}
t_{ij}y_{ij}, & \text{ if } y_{ij}\leq B_{ij}\\
t_{ij}B_{ij}+r_{ij}(y_{ij}-B_{ij}), & \text{ if } y_{ij}> B_{ij}\\
\end{cases}$$ We can simplify that as follows : $$TC_{ij}=t_{ij}\cdot \min(y_{ij}, B_{ij})+r_{ij}\cdot \max(0, y_{ij}-B_{ij})$$
The total production cost is then $$totalPC=\sum_{i=1}^m\left (c_i\cdot \min(x_i, A_i)+k_i\cdot \max(0, x_i-A_i)\right )$$ and the total transportation cost is $$totalTC=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\left (t_{ij}\cdot \min(y_{ij}, B_{ij})+r_{ij}\cdot \max(0, y_{ij}-B_{ij})\right )$$
That means that the mathematical formulation of the above problem is :
$$\min Z \\ Z\geq \sum_{i=1}^m\left (c_i\cdot \min(x_i, A_i)+k_i\cdot \max(0, x_i-A_i)\right )\\ Z\geq \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\left (t_{ij}\cdot \min(y_{ij}, B_{ij})+r_{ij}\cdot \max(0, y_{ij}-B_{ij})\right ) \\ \sum_{i=1}^my_{ij}=d_j, \forall j=1,\dots,n \\ \sum_{j=1}^ny_{ij}\leq x_i, \forall i=1, \dots, m \\ x_i, y_{ij}\geq 0, \forall i,j$$ where $Z=\max(totalPC, totalTC)$
Is everything correct so far?
Is this problem solvable by hand although the existence of these min and max functions or do we have to solve these by python/matlab?

Is there any relation between $c_i$ and $\kappa_i$, like maybe $c_i \le \kappa_i$?  Same question about $t_{ij}$ and $r_{ij}$.

No, there are no further information.
